Expo Go crashes when updating to SDK 51
I just updated my project' SDK because the expo GO IOS app updated automatically to SDK51.
My project works fine with SDK 50.
But after updating, I got error:
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx ./",
    "lint-fix": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx ./ --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.23.10",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.17",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.15",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.1",
    "antd": "^5.12.2",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.1.0",
    "expo": "^51.0.0",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.1",
    "expo-camera": "~15.0.6",
    "expo-image-picker": "~15.0.4",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-media-library": "~16.0.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "firebase": "^10.11.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moti": "^0.28.1",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "radio-buttons-react-native": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.3.0",
    "react-native-popover-view": "^5.1.8",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-redash": "^18.1.2",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-switch": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.79",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.73.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}


Help me pls. Thanks all.
I tried to update the react native version and some others solutions on stack overflow but it did not work.

update the expo go app, it will fix the issue. and check any outdated package with 'npx expo-doctor@latest --fix' command. hope this will fix the issue. I just did it now.

got the same issue and this one helped me :
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/28618

Please explain the solution here instead of adding link. thanks

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I was getting the same error the what I did is that I deleted the node_modules and package_lock.json when and than ran npm install again all the errors were removed but then when i started the app it is not starting instead it shows something went wrong ( Network response timed out ) "

same issue? did you fix?

My Package.json file is:
{
  "name": "nhdp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.1.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "expo": "^51.0.1",
    "expo-blur": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.1",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.1",
    "expo-document-picker": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-image": "~1.12.9",
    "expo-image-picker": "~15.0.5",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.14",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.3",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.13.1",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.1.2",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-inset-shadow": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-pdf-viewer": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webview": "13.8.6",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "sha3": "^2.1.4",
    "universal-tooltip": "^1.1.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

and I can not navigate between screens. I have imported "react-native-reanimated" to my app.js file but still Expo go crashes when I navigate between screens.
